# How to show that $\sum_{m = 1}^n e^{imx}$ is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that there exists some $M$ such that for any $n$ and any $x \in [\epsilon, 2\pi - \epsilon]$ we have $\left |\sum_{m = 1}^n e^{imx} \right|\leq M$. Geometrically, it is like starting at the origin facing east, then turning left by $x$ degrees and moving forward by 1 unit of distance, and repeating this $n$ times. We want to show that the spot you end up is always less than some distance $M$ from the origin. From this geometric interpretation, it is clear that this is the case since $x$ is at least $\epsilon$ and at most $2\pi - \epsilon$. However, how can I show this algebraically?

Comment: Just sum up the series - it is a sum of powers.

Comment: @uniquesolution so $\frac{e^{i(n+1)x} - e^{ix}}{e^{ix} - 1}$?

Comment: @i_hate_math -- Also note that absolute values are essential here. When you submit your homework, don't forget them.

Comment: @uniquesolution okay, but actually it is supposed to be iheartmath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote in your comment, and then

$$\left|\frac{e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{ix}}{e^{ix}-1}\right|=\frac{|(e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{ix})(e^{-ix}-1)|}{|e^{ix}-1|^2}\le\frac{2\cdot2}{2|1-\cos x|}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just sum up the series:

$$\sum_{m=1}^ne^{imx}=\frac{e^{ix}(e^{inx}-1)}{e^{ix}-1}$$

and note that
$$|e^{ix}-1|=\sqrt{2|1-\cos x|}$$

Now, for $x\in[\varepsilon,2\pi-\varepsilon]$, one has:
$$ |1-\cos x|\geq 1-\cos\varepsilon$$
It follows that for all $n$ and $x\in[\varepsilon,2\pi-\varepsilon]$
$$\left |\frac{e^{ix}(e^{inx}-1)}{e^{ix}-1}\right|\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2(1-\cos\varepsilon)}}$$